# Load resistance what if

Tags: bjt

If I use a NPN transistor in common emitter configuration.

Now imagine that I saturate the transistor for a certain load resistor.

What would happen if I draw the load resistor up higher, 200 kΩ for example?

Would the transistor be more saturated or would it affect at all?
[image]

Comment: By "load resistor" do you mean a resistor connected from Vout to ground? Or do you mean (as I suspect) the collector resistor Rc?

Comment: I mean the collector resistor Rc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you remember the definition for saturation?

The npn transistor is in saturation state when the potential of the collector is (wrong:larger) smaller than the potential of the base.

That means: The pn junction between B and C is forward biased - and there is not only a current between B and E but also between B and C.
Therefore, the popular relation between Ib and (Ib=Ic/B) does not apply anymore - the current into the base node is larger than anticipated by this relation.

Now - ask yourself: What happens with the collector potential when there is - in addition to the collector resistor Rc - an additional load RL (DC coupled)...and what will happen when you play with this load.

Comment: Saturation can also be viewed as when the collector is starved of current. In which case, further decreasing the collector current obviously causes it to remain starved.

Comment: In my point of view it should starve and saturate further with even higher resistance on Rc.

Comment: The npn transistor is NOT in saturation state when the potential of the collector is larger than the potential of the base.

Comment: Yes - in my posting there was a typing error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean the collector resistor Rc

If the transistor is in saturation, and you increase the value of Rc, the transistor will go "deeper" into saturation.

The collector current will definitely decrease.

The collector to emitter voltage, Vce, will decrease, but in some analyses, you might treat that decrease as "negligible". If the transistor is in "deep" saturation to begin with, with a Vce of around 0.2V, one is more likely to treat the decrease in Vce as "negligible".

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be answered by drawing the load line of the common emitter configuration.

[image]

If the operating point Q is found where the function is a straight line then the transistor is amplyfing  base current.

If the operating point Q is found where the function is increasing then the transistor is saturated.

Notice that if we take the limit of RL->\$\infty\$ then VCE becomes 0.But as seen from the diagram as we increase the load resistance in a saturated transistor the decrease in VCE as RL is increasing isnt linear so VCE will very very slowly approach 0 as RL->\$\infty\$